# Producing heatmap using geom_raster() makes different results in PDF and display

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I am trying to produce heatmap using geom_raster() of ggplot2. Here is the code:

```
foo <- matrix(1:999,ncol=3)
ggplot(melt(foo), aes(X2,X1, fill=value)) + geom_raster()
```

The result is:

[image]

But the result is so different while casting the output to a PDF file (using `pdf()` function):

[image]

There are many columns, with colors gradually changing between the columns. How to have the same heatmap as the first one while casting the output to PDF file?

Comment: Nothing looks particularly wrong to me. Can you provide a reproducible example and explain more fully what sort of image you expected?

Comment: Some pdf viewers don't like grid.raster, even with interpolate=FALSE they show some spurious gradient. Have you tried e.g. png?

Comment: your pdf most probably **is** good, it's the world of pdf viewers that is deficient. Try to see if you have some preferences in the viewer to turn off interpolation and/or a different pdf viewer.

Comment: @Ali what system are you on? Have you tried `ggsave` and have you tried `geom_tile` instead? All combinations work perfectly for me (including `pdf` with `geom_raster`)

Comment: in Mac's `preview` application, i can switch "smooth text and line art" off and see the expected output. There's a similar option in the cross-platform Adobe Reader, try it.

Comment: @SimonO101 Thanks for your great `ggsave` solution

Comment: @baptiste switching "smooth text and line art" off made the expected output, although text rendering was not good at all. So it seems having output in PNG file could be a better choice. Would you please make your comment as the answer to be accepted?

Comment: it sort of depends what you want to do with the output (e.g. things should be fine in print). With few tiles, there is little benefit of using raster over geom_tile anyway, so I'd use the former, while for large number of tiles, interpolation on/off should make less of a difference. The intermediate regime remains problematic in terms of portability, so perhaps png is a good compromise there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some pdf viewers don't manage properly the output of `grid.raster`, even with `interpolate=FALSE` they insist on showing some spurious gradient. 
Your pdf most probably is good (as per the pdf format specifications), it's the pdf viewer that is deficient (overzealous to smooth).

Try to see if you have some preferences in the viewer to turn off interpolation and/or a different pdf viewer, e.g. in Mac's Preview application, one can switch "smooth text and line art" off and see the expected output. There's a similar option in the cross-platform Adobe Reader.

Comment: As @baptiste pointed out on another question, sometimes geom_tile() does not have this problem.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/349090/is-it-possible-make-preview-not-enhance-thin-lines shows that the OS X preview app smooths, and removed the option to stop smoothing.